# Running multiple threads of a service

Tags: android, multithreading, service

My Android UI has a list of objects that can be "synced for offline use", each row has a progress bar that indicates how many map tiles have been downloaded by the Service.

I want to implement an Android service which should do the following

- Download data related to an object (on user clic), this data is map tiles (images) from OpenStreetMaps, so I need to estimate the number of tiles and tell the UI how many will be (for a progress bar)
- Notify updates to the UI for each object (listview with each row with a progress bar)

Should I implement a binded service that runs multiple threads? or a service that handles one data download process each?, the latter would be probably simpler to communicate progress to the UI thread.

I need guidance on concepts to investigate more than code (Must be a lot of code)

Thanks.

Comment: A bit more information about your project's specific functional requirements would be handy here.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html). You just need to give all the url of the files you want to download and it will do it automatically. Of course it handles all of connectivity issue, resume download, continue after phone reboot, restrict download to wifi, etc.

In addition you need to register a `BroadcastReceiver` for `android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_COMPLETE` and you will be notified everytime a file has been downloaded.

There is a small example : [here](http://blog.vogella.com/2011/06/14/android-downloadmanager-example/).

Comment: Thanks! Didnt know about it. The thing is that I am downloading map tiles from OpenStreetMaps, so I need to process all the tiles needed in my service.

Comment: You can still use it. It will just download the files, then it's up to you do to what you need with it. You can execute any code you want when the broadcastreceiver is called.

Comment: Yes, but I still don't know how to implement the service that estimates the number of tiles to be downloaded and notify individual rows.